# htaccess redirect subfolder to root and force https

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all URLs with a subfolder to the root, but also force https and www
So, for example, I want to redirect:

```
example.com/shop/category/product
www.example.com/shop/category/product
example.com/SHOP/category/product
```

- to

  https://www.example.com/category/product

I've tried the following code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1
```

but this doesn't redirect the subfolder, and if I add the subfolder as a previous rule like

```
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

It just doesn't work.

One thing to point out - I must also make sure that any other requests to the site (with or without the subfolder) are being redirected to the https www version.

Can anybody point me in the right direction or help me solve this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use this single rule for this redirect at **top of your .htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:shop/)?.*$ https://www.%1/$0 [R=301,L,NC,NE]

# rest of your rules go below
```

Make sure to clear browser cache or use a new browser for testing.